# Derive two different arrays from a single array in php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

There is an array named $counts with output

```
array:3 [
0 => {
"applied_date": "10-10"
"count": 1
}
1 => {
"applied_date": "10-14"
"count": 1
}
2 => {
"applied_date": "10-15"
"count": 1
}
]
```

I want to build two different arrays with applied date and its value from each array and count from each array in php. Is it under associative array or anything else? I'm new to php.

Comment: Better you can use `array_column()` function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below code for your solution

```
<?php
// Array representing a possible record set returned from a database
$records = array(
    array(
        "applied_date"=> "10-10",
        "count"=> 1
    ),
    array(
        "applied_date"=> "10-10",
        "count"=> 1
    ),
    array(
        "applied_date"=> "10-10",
        "count"=> 1
    )
);

$applied_date = array_column($records, 'applied_date');
$count = array_column($records, 'count');
print_r($applied_date);
print_r($count);


?>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: make sure your PHP version will be `(PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7)`

Comment: You have forgotten to add comma in your array example.

Comment: getting this error "Array to string conversion" when I use my array name $counts instead of $records.

Comment: can you post your on pastebin ?

Comment: also paste `$counts` array there in pastebin.

Comment: Got it, you are doing `echo $applied_date` instead that use `print_r($applied_date)` because `$applied_date` and `$count` both will be array not string!

Comment: I posted the output that i get when I use dd($counts) to display it in my php file

Comment: read my comment above. as you are trying to `echo` array that will be giving you error. try `print_r` instead that.

Comment: Array ( ) Array ( ) Im getting this output

Comment: seems like you are not passing proper array. your array should be like this http://pastebin.com/gWsi1qdK

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the `$counts` array and push each element to new arrays like so:

```
$applied_dates_arr = [];
$count_arr = []

foreach ($counts as $el) {
    $applied_dates_arr[] = $el['applied_date'];
    $count_arr[] = $el['count'];
}
```

Comment: but this gives me an error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: So you are using a class? not an array?

Comment: yes I'm  using laravel frame work and the resultant object is what I get from query.

Comment: this thing works with multidimensional arrays but not with the output that I'm getting.